# Node.js - Why my two queries are not executed?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I know that Node.js is asynchronous, but I don't know why my two queries are not executing, only the first query. I just tried to put query if first query is Ok, but even though the second query does not execute.

Here is my code:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO TB_DISPOSITIVOS_VOZ (DS_CLIENTID, FK_ID_GRUPO) ";
sql = sql + " VALUES ('" + alexaClientId + "', " + idgrupo + ") ";

connection.query(sql, function(erro2, rows2, fields2) {

  if (!erro2) {
    console.log("Inserted alexa in the group: " + idgrupo + "with the clientId: " + alexaClientId);                                     
   } else {
    console.log("Error - When inserting alexa in the group" + erro2);
    context.fail("Error - When inserting alexa in the group" + erro2);
   }

});

sql1 = "DELETE FROM TB_FILA_PAREAMENTO_OTP WHERE DS_CLIENTID = '" + alexaClientId + "'";

connection.query(sql1, function(erro3, rows3, fields3) {

  if (!erro3) {
    console.log("Query Delete TB_FILA_PAREAMENTO_OTP OK");
  } else {
    console.log("Error - Delete query does not works correctly..." + erro3);
    context.fail("Error - Delete query does not works correctly..." + erro3);
  }

});
```

Comment: What package do you use for mysql ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved my problem.

Using multiple statements like this:

flag multistatements in connection:

```
multipleStatements: true

sql = "INSERT INTO TB_1 (DS_CLIENTID, FK_ID_GRUPO) ";
sql = sql + " VALUES ('" + alexaClientId + "', " + idgrupo + "); ";
sql1 = "DELETE FROM TB_2 WHERE DS_CLIENTID = '" + alexaClientId + "';";
sql2 = "DELETE FROM TB_3 WHERE DS_CLIENTID = '" + alexaClientId + "';";

sql = sql2 + sql + sql1; 

connection.query(sql,[1,2,3], function(erro2, rows2, fields2) {
    if (!erro2) {
        console.log("Inserted alexa in the group: " + idgrupo + "with the clientId: " + alexaClientId);
    } else {
        console.log("Error - When inserting alexa in the group" + erro2);
        context.fail("Error - When inserting alexa in the group" + erro2);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Q github promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/q)

```
var Q = require('Q');



function query1(){

var defered = Q.defer();
sql = "INSERT INTO TB_DISPOSITIVOS_VOZ (DS_CLIENTID, FK_ID_GRUPO) ";
sql = sql + " VALUES ('" + alexaClientId + "', " + idgrupo + ") ";

connection.query(sql, function(erro2, rows2, fields2) {

    if (!erro2) {
        console.log("Inserted alexa in the group: " + idgrupo + "with the clientId: " + alexaClientId);

    } else {
        console.log("Error - When inserting alexa in the group" + erro2);
        context.fail("Error - When inserting alexa in the group" + erro2);
    }

});

return defered.promise;

}



function query2(){
var defered = Q.defer();
sql1 = "DELETE FROM TB_FILA_PAREAMENTO_OTP WHERE DS_CLIENTID = '" + alexaClientId + "'";

connection.query(sql1, function(erro3, rows3, fields3) {

    if (!erro3) {
        console.log("Query Delete TB_FILA_PAREAMENTO_OTP OK");
    } else {
        console.log("Error - Delete query does not works correctly..." + erro3);
        context.fail("Error - Delete query does not works correctly..." + erro3);
    }

});    
 return defered.promise;
}

Q.all([query1(),query2()]).then(function(results){

        console.log('all done');
    });
```